# How can i change the position of html error message validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

Having trouble in the html validation because of how its position tried removing table and resizing the input text box still the same out of position

[image]

addform.php

here is the form tried to resize the input textbox but still the error validation message is still out of position

```
   <style type="text/css">
  #dis{
   display:none;
  }


  </style>




    <div id="dis">
    <!-- here message will be displayed -->
    </div>


 <form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#">

<table class='table table-bordered'>

    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='fname' class='form-control' 
        pattern ="[a-zA-Z]+"
        title="First Name should only contain letters"


         required /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='lname' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Contact Number</td>
        <td><input type='number' name='contactnum' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' required /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name='pass' class='form-control'  required /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='lang' class='form-control'  required /></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save" id="btn-save">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save this User
        </button>  
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

still new in doing front end hope you can help me thanks

Comment: how is the error message added? need to see the code and any associated CSS or inline style for that error messsage

Comment: just using pattern ,regex and title

Comment: well the answer is equally vague - fix the code and CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs a position:absolute, then you can move it anywhere you'd like on the page.

```
 #dis {
       position: absolute;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding this code in CSS, you can customize the required (error message).

```
.form-control[required] {
    margin-top: 40px !important; // change pixels according to your need.
    margin-left: 130px !important; // change pixels according to your need.
}
```